# Lower Temp Thermostat for Forced Induction?

Tags: temperature, cooling, thermostat, super-charger, forced-induction

Is there a case to be made for a low temp. thermostat for a factory N/A engine that has been supercharged? I am considering a future project where I'd supercharge a 2L engine, running a modest 7-8 psi or so max. I would want to upgrade the factory radiator to a performance variant to help manage heat, as well as a low temp. thermostat, about 10 degrees (F) lower than normal. My goal would be to combat some of the heat associated with forced induction and help my engine survive longer. What do you guys think? I've searched forums and people seem very polarized about low temp thermostats. Again, I'd be using it in conjunction with an upgraded radiator.

Answer (score 0):

is this thermostat in the engine controlling the flow of water or the electric thermostat (sensor) that manages the electric fan?

If the engine thermostat:

- It will be more proper to use the default thermostat
- If you are unsure about the original thermostat, you can try to search for an upgraded version in your local shop or amazon which specially build for your card type.
- If you can't find anything, never change to unoriginal custom made in China (this is a very bad idea considering you are using supercharged)
- In old wives tales, if you remove the thermostat there is no flow restriction meaning your engine will cooler than before. (In tropical countries, 3rd world country this is a common procedure to remove the thermostat because it useless and many times this is a problem maker because the thermostat fail to open)

If you mean the electric fan sensor:

- Buying the lower temp sensor is good to go even is unbranded, but your electric consumption will be increased, I don't sure how is your alternator go.
- Lower temp = more frequent the fan is running.
- Alternative = you can try to make it manual switch to turn on the fan if you can.